# How to get the scripts parsing time?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having a html page with some scripts. I want to measure the time taken for the individual scripts to parse. So i would like to add time stamps before and after script elements. How can i do it through javascript/AOP?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="a.js"></script>
    <script src="b.js"></script>
    <script src="c.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="d.js"></script>
    <script src="e.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: i don't want to use any tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the time taken for the load event on the window to fire, from the time the page was requested a better measurement on which approach to go for.

The time taken to download the page is important, and a file always been cached after 1st load is only ever true in a perfect world.

You can also `console.time("Parsetime")` and `console.timeEnd("Parsetime")`.

or

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
/* Run a test. */
var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
```

Comment: Assume i have 100s of scripts in my page, and i need to measure all the scripts time. Do i need to instrument before and after of each script?

Comment: If your not using tools, then yes. If it's just parse times you want, why are you not just using developer tools in the browser to check that.